# How to correctly store and process different measure units of ingredients in food service CMS?

Tags: storing-data, storing-information

I have a backend system for restaurants & food services. On the front end people are using a huge variety of measure units for recipes and such (kilo, cup, gallon, pint, small spoon, big spoon, pinch of salt, dash of pepper and so on). But i need to convert all that to something small and **indivisible** to make calculations, reports and analytics and the backend. However, to show some info and reports to the user i have to convert all the stuff backwards to the 'user-friendly' measure units.

Thus it can lead to errors in numbers (round-off errors and such).

What is the best practice to deal with that? Thank you!

Comment: Try to stick to ISU (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units). You can then round the transformed values (you should get roughly the same value). This rounding will not be a significant loss (and as far as i know, in cooking, there's no visible difference between 1kg and 999 grams)